Replacing CommonMultipartFile with MultipartFile
In the code, I have used CommonMultipartFile.getStorageDescription() to get the file location. Now, as CommonMultipartFile has been discontinued from spring 3, I need to replace this with MultipartFile. In MultipartFile there is no getStorageDescription() method. How do I get the location of the file using MultipartFile?
I tried MultipartFile.getResource().getDescription() but this method will not give me the file location. I need the location of the file.

Why do you need the location? That seems to be a smell in the first place. To copy to somehwere else use the InputStream available from the MultipartFile.

MultipartFile doesn’t provide a direct way to get the file location. If you need the file path, you can save the file explicitly and retrieve its location:
MultipartFile file = // your MultipartFile instance;
String location = "/path/to/save/" + file.getOriginalFilename();
File savedFile = new File(location);

try {
    file.transferTo(savedFile);
    System.out.println("File saved at: " + savedFile.getAbsolutePath());
} catch (IOException e) {
    e.printStackTrace();
}

If you’re using CommonsMultipartFile, you can get the temporary file location, but this approach depends on the specific implementation:
if (multipartFile instanceof CommonsMultipartFile) {
    DiskFileItem fileItem = (DiskFileItem) ((CommonsMultipartFile) multipartFile).getFileItem();
    System.out.println("Temp location: " + fileItem.getStoreLocation().getAbsolutePath());
}

The recommended approach is to manage file saving explicitly for better control and portability.
